# How to open a new terminal session and automatically run some commands

Tags: gnome-terminal

My task is to run a new terminal session and in that terminal session logon to a remote server then run some commands. Example:

Terminal1:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title "servername" -- /bin/sh -c "script servername.`date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'`; ssh user@serverip; <execute some more commands after logon to server>"
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Oracle Linux 7.